# A login page handling an exception and redirect to another page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a login page and a.cs page.

The login Page is designed

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="IssueTrak.UserInterface.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" placeholder="User Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Login" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the .CS page is designed

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BusinessLogic objBussinessLogic = new BusinessLogic();
                string userName = objBussinessLogic.Authenticate(login,password);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                {
                    Session["username"] = userName;
                    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx",true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Invalid Login.')", true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Issue.aspx", false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The issue is when i enter the User name and password that is available in the DB, it should return to Home.aspx rather it is going directly to catch where did i  made a mistake. I have designed my code in 3 tier architecture, i have provided only little info i have not provided my DB connection part. Just i want to redirect to Home.aspx when i enter correct credentials

Comment: check what is the error in catch exception. and share here... also check the **userName** string should not be **blank** or **null**

Comment: wt exception you are getting??

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal. I am not getting the error , i am directly redirect to Issue.aspx page after login with correct credential without going to Home.aspx page. I have the breakpoint where it comes directly to catch and redirect me to Issue.aspx page

Comment: @KeerthiKumar I am not getting the error , i am directly redirect to Issue.aspx page after login with correct credential without going to Home.aspx page. I have the breakpoint where it comes directly to catch and redirect me to Issue.aspx page

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal It is not blank in the backend

Comment: If i take those try and catch then i am getting output as expected

Comment: If your breakpoint in `catch` is hit, could you give us the content of the variable `ex`?

Comment: `Response.Redirect("something", true)` throws `ThreadAbortException`. You catch it in your `catch` block and you redirect to `Issue.aspx`

Comment: @HariharanV - there must be some error message in **ex** please provide that message

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code and description... the program works correctly. You said: `when i enter the User name and password that is available in the DB, it should return to Home.aspx` , that is really going to redirect to Home.aspx, because you enter a valid `username` and `password` , and let say you enter a wrong `username` and `password` , you will not be redirected to `Issue.aspx` since it is only invalid.

You will only redirected to Issue.aspx **IF** the system encounter a system Exception, because you put your code in catch block:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Issue.aspx", false);
}
```

Comment: I am entering a valid Credentials , and i should have redirected to Home.aspx. Instead my breakpoint falls directly in catch and throws Issue.aspx

Comment: @HariharanV ah i see, you should be redirected to Home.aspx , ahm do you have the error message ? , just put a breakpoint and let see if what is the error message.. it could be something in connection to database i think.

Comment: See with break point only it is going to all the methods and accessing those fields in the methods , i am using a 3 tier architecture so it goes via Data logic layer, business layer and application layer from there it will come to login.aspx catch block and display issue.aspx page. I have written a customized error Something happened click back to go to login page

Comment: @HariharanV , yup i understand you are working in a 3-tier , my suspect is in the DataAccessLayer , ahn can you show your Business and Data Layer code for this `objBussinessLogic.Authenticate(login,password)` ? , I am pretty sure you encounter system error, thats why it will catch the exception, it will also give you a message in the `ex` under `catch` , can you give us the message ?

Comment: I have edited my question and added data logic layer

Answer (score 0):

[`Response.Redirect("something", true)` throws `ThreadAbortException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for
>   one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to
>   false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true
>   for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for
>   the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception
>   when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web
>   application performance, which is why passing false for the
>   endResponse parameter is recommended.

You catch it in your `catch` block and you redirect to Issue.aspx.

You can add a specific exception handler for `ThreadAbortException`

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Issue.aspx", false);
}
catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
{
}
```

Or call `Redirect` with second parameter(`endResponse`) set to `false`

```
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx", false);
```